# drupal 9 yml installition cant find dependencies

Tags: php, drupal, yaml, drupal-9

I did export my modules, then make a clean drupal installation. Then I separate the yml files into modules. I put every related yml files under config/install in my module folder. But when I hit the install it won't install my modules. Gives error and says
`Unable to install *my_module* due to unmet dependencies:....`
But the dependent files are already inside the folder.

Comment: I exported my drupal configurations with Configuration > Development > Synchronize > export > full archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem by separating media and other types into optional folder under config folder and by giving 777 permission to every yml file. İf you are sure that you have all dependencies give 777 permission to yml files.